# Why the Text can’t be at the center of the screen and why there’s a huge space above the text?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I’m using the SwiftUI and I got my `HStack` texts aligned by their `lastTextBaseline`.

But there’s a huge space above the text and the whole stack just can’t be at the center of the screen.

It looks like this:

[image]

My code:

```
struct SwiftUIViewTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            ZStack{
                Rectangle()
                VStack(alignment: .center){
                    HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline){
                        Text("3")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: nil, height: (geometry.size.height-10)/2.5, alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .firstTextBaseline))
                            .font(.bold(.system(size: 100))())
                            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .shadow(radius: 2)
                        Text("cups")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .shadow(radius: 2)
                    }
                    Text("next cup on")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                        .opacity(0.5)
                    Text("10 : 00")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .shadow(radius: 1)
                        .opacity(0.5)
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're explicitly setting the height of the `Text("3")` to `(geometry.size.height-10)/2.5`. This is much more height than it needs, which is the "huge space above the text".

In this case, not only do you not need this `frame` modifier, you don't need the `GeometryReader` either, since it was only functioning to give you the measurement for the un-needed frame.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Rectangle()
            VStack(alignment: .center){
                HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline){
                    Text("3")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.bold(.system(size: 100))())
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                    Text("cups")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                }
                Text("next cup on")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .shadow(radius: 2)
                    .opacity(0.5)
                Text("10 : 00")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .shadow(radius: 1)
                    .opacity(0.5)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I’m trying to let the font size adapt to the screen size proportionally just like what we’ve done in storyboard: adding the height constraint to the text and setting the minimum font size. I saw other people do the same in SwiftUI and it seems to work fine… how can I do now?

Comment: You're explicitly setting the `fontSize` to `100`. The `frame` modifier doesn't change the font size (unless you have a font that gets compressed to fit into a smaller size). You could put the `GeometryReader` back into and use it to calculate a number for `fontSize` (I don't know what you're formula is), but it won't change the significant part of this answer, which is that the "huge space above the text" is caused by your `height` modifier.

Comment: Ok. I’ll calculate the font size instead. Thanks.

Comment: Sure -- for example, if you use `.font(.bold(.system(size: 4000))())`, it'll grow to the largest size the screen can accommodate. But, you may want it smaller -- so, you could use that `GeometryReader` measurement/calculation you had before.